# How can I obtain total number of points?

Tags: macros, counters

I defined the command:

```
\newcommand{\shcpoint}[1]{%
    \ifnum #1<2
        (\emph{#1 point})\quad\phantom{s}%
    \else
        (\emph{#1 points})\quad%
    \fi
    }
```

and I use it in the following form:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \shcpoint{2} Some random question
 \item \shcpoint{3} Other question
\end{enumerate}
\totalshcpoints
\end{document}
```

The question is, how can I store the points somewhere, maybe in the `.aux` file and then add it to find the total in the document or section where it is used (globally and locally). I am aware that this is a feature used by the `exam` class and other packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `totcount` you can register a counter and use the total everywhere (requires two LaTeX runs to stabilize).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{totcount}
\newcounter{totalpoints}
\regtotcounter{totalpoints}

\newcommand{\shcpoint}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{totalpoints}{#1}%
  \ifnum#1<2
    (\emph{#1 point})\hphantom{\em s}%
  \else
    (\emph{#1 points})%
  \fi\quad
}

\begin{document}
This questionary has a total of \total{totalpoints}~points.
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \shcpoint{1} Easy question
 \item \shcpoint{2} Some random question
 \item \shcpoint{3} Other question
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

latex counters are global so you can just do

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{pts}
\newcommand{\shcpoint}[1]{%
\addtocounter{pts}{#1}%
    \ifnum #1<2
        (\emph{#1 point})\quad\phantom{s}%
    \else
        (\emph{#1 points})\quad%
    \fi
    }

\newcommand\totalshcpoints{\thepts}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item \shcpoint{2} Some random question
 \item \shcpoint{3} Other question
\end{enumerate}
\totalshcpoints
\end{document}
```