# How to add the total marks using probsoln

Tags: counters, probsoln

I am trying to add the total marks at the end of an exam paper using probsoln. All the questions are in a seperate file and I just use `\loadallproblems` to add them to the exam paper. I add the number of marks for each question in the "Question File" with `\marginpar{[\marklabel{2}]}`. Is there any way (other than adding it manually!) to add all the marks together and add this number at the bottom of the exam paper? Here is the code I am using, I can't find any way to add this total:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{probsoln}
\newcounter{myprob}
\newenvironment{myproblems}
  {\par\setcounter{myprob}{0}}
  {\par}
\newcommand\MyProb{%
  {\par\medskip\centering\refstepcounter{myprob}{\LARGE \bfseries Question : Vraag \arabic{myprob}}\par\bigskip}%
  }

\renewcommand{\solutionname}{\bfseries MEMORANDUM}
 \loadallproblems{Questions}

 \showanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{myproblems}
\foreachproblem{\MyProb\thisproblem}
\end{myproblems}

\end{document}
\endinput
```

Would appreciate any help!!

Comment: Does [How can I obtain total number of points?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142676/how-can-i-obtain-total-number-of-points) help?

Comment: Do you mind if we close your question as a duplicate then?